# Iterating over asyncio coroutines/Tasks as soon as they are ready

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I launch a bunch of requests using `aiohttp`. Is there a way to get the results one-by-one as soon as each request is complete?

Perhaps using something like `async for`? Or Python 3.6 async generators?

Currently I `await asyncio.gather(*requests)` and process them when all of them are completed.

Answer (score 5):

`asyncio` has [as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) function that probably does what you need. Note, it returns regular iterator, not async.

Here's example of usage:

```
import asyncio


async def test(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    return i


async def main():
    fs = [
        test(1),
        test(2),
        test(3),
    ]

    for f in asyncio.as_completed(fs):
        i = await f  # Await for next result.
        print(i, 'done')



loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
```

Output:

```
1 done
2 done
3 done
```

Answer (score 1):

Canonical way is pushing result into `asyncio.Queue` like in [crawler example](https://github.com/aosabook/500lines/tree/master/crawler/code).
Also it's wise to run limited amount for download tasks which get new job from input queue instead of spawning a million of new tasks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand according to the docs, `requests` are `Future`s (or can be easily converted to Future using [asyncio.ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future)).

A `Future` object has a method `.add_done_callback`. 
So, you can add your callback for every request, and then do `gather`.

[Docs for Future.add_done_callback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback)

Comment: Don't use `add_done_callback` until you are writing something very low level.